# Removing NULL / empty fields

Tags: shell, null, unix, awk

just wanted to check with you could this be done better:

```
awk -F"\t" '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "NULL") {
            printf("%s%s", $i, FS);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}' file1
```

The goal is to print only non-`NULL` fields. For example:

```
echo "TestRecord001 NULL    NULL    Age 29  NULL    NULL    Name    John" | awk -F"\t" '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "NULL") {
            printf("%s%s", $i, FS);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}'
```

will print out: `TestRecord001  Age 29  Name    John`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same behaviour can be achieved using `sed` as follows:

```
echo -e 'TestRecord001\tNULL\tNULL\tAge\t29\tNULL\tNULL\tName\tJohn' | sed '
s/$/\t/;
s/\(\tNULL\)\+\t/\t/g;
s/^NULL\t//';
```

Explanation:

`sed s/SearchPattern/Replacement/g`. Here `s` indicates that replacement operation is to be done. Strings matching `SearchPattern` will be replaced by `Replacement`. `g` indicates that the operation will have to be performed on every match and not just on the first occurrence in a line.

1. `s/$/\t/` adds a tab to the end of each line. [`$` matches the end of a line]
2. `\(\tNULL\)\+\t` matches a string of the form `\tNULL\tNULL...NULL\t`. This is replaced with `\t`.
3. After this the only remaining NULL is the one at the beginning of a line (without `\t` to its left). This is matched by `^NULL\t` and replaced with the empty string. [`^` matches the beginning of a line]

Comment: My previous answer was incorrect because NULL\(\t\|$\) matches with the ending portion of This-entry-is-not-NULL\t (which it shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

### Your code is good.

I can't see anything to improve upon in your original code.

### awk vs other tools (e.g sed)

I think awk is a good tool for this as you are dealing with input that has clearly defined fields and field separators.  The code seems more readable in awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can print only non `NULL` values by using this simple `awk` command:

```
echo -e 'TestRecord001\tNULL\tNULL\tAge\t29\tNULL\tNULL\tName\tJohn' | awk -F"\t" '{gsub("NULL\t*","")}1'
```

`gsub` changes the record such that any occurence with NULL followed by a tab is deleted.